# The item's lifetime of global HashMap by lazy_static in Rust

Tags: rust, static, lifetime, lazy-static

I am new to Rust.

I define a global HashMap of `User` by `lazy_static`.

There is a lifetime in `User`, so I have to set a lifetime in `lazy_static`. It seems that only `'static` can be used in `lazy_static`.

Here is the question: can I insert "non-static" User into the HashMap now?

Here is the code, which inserts a non-static User:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct User<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    score: f32,
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref USERS: Mutex<HashMap<u64, User<'static>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

fn new_user(id: u64, name: &str, score: f32) {
    let user = User { name, score };
    USERS.lock().unwrap().insert(id, user);
}
fn remove_user(id: u64) {
    USERS.lock().unwrap().remove(&id);
}

fn main() {
    new_user(1, "hello", 1.2);
    remove_user(1);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `name`
  --> src/main.rs:16:38
   |
16 |     USERS.lock().unwrap().insert(id, user);
   |                                      ^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

Comment: You can't - since `lazy_static` keeps the object alive until the end of the program, accepting any lifetime other than `'static` would allow a reference inside the stored value (such as `name` in case of the `User` type) to become invalid while still in the hash map. The `User` struct should hold an owned `String` instead of `&str`.

Comment: Thanks. I can change the name to `String`, but there will be other reference in `User`, such as `&Class`. It can not hold everything.

Comment: Should I use `Arc<Class>` to replace `&Class` ?

Comment: That, or just `Class`, depending on the use case.

Comment: I doubt using a lazy static on your case make sense. xy problem we have here

Comment: @user4815162342 There will be many users (or students) who belong to a same class. So just `Class` should not be OK.

Comment: @Stargateur I am writing a school management service (to learn Rust) which has some web APIs to add/update/delete User. These API handlers all need to access a User-map. If I write it in C, this User-map must be a file-static variable.

Comment: @BingzhengWu I doubt I will ever do that in C for this case. I would clearly simply use a struct that contains the hashmap.

Comment: @Stargateur Then how do you access this struct in many handlers? by passing it as argument? Assuming it is created in main(), then pass it as `main()->thread_entry()->callback_if_network_readable->parse_request()->command_handlers[cmd]()`.

Comment: yes of course, unless I have a very good reason I would never use static. In fact I mostly only use static for application OPTIONS. Also, your question is theoretical, thus it's really hard to answer you, for example, in rocket, one should use `State` and would have no problem sharing the state of the API in multi thread environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236530/discussion-between-bingzheng-wu-and-stargateur).

Comment: Then `Arc<Class>` it is - case closed. While Rust does discourage global variables a bit more than most languages, there are cases when they are perfectly useful. If you have reason to believe you're dealing with such a case, just go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to have a list of `User`s in each `Class`, and each `User` has a unique `id`, just store the `id`s in each instance of `Class` (and wherever else you would've had a reference to a `User`). `u64` is `Clone`, so it all works.